# Using Jquery what background and specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change background color and specific text

```
$(".director-info").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
   $(this).find(".director-info h2").css("color", "#000000");
    $(this).find(".director-info h3").css("color", "#605F5F");
```

Problem Solve but I can't stop the mouseover event after mouseleave. Please Help

Comment: What do you mean by stopping the mouseover event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this -- Edit for mouseleave

```js
 $(".director-info").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
    $(this).find("h2").css("color", "#000000");
    $(this).find("h3").css("color", "#605F5F");
});
    
    
 $(".director-info").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "#eee");
   $(this).find("h2").css("color", "#000000");
    $(this).find("h3").css("color", "#000");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="director-info" >
  <h2>Hi</h2>
  <h3>Hello</h3>
</div>
```

Notice you are using find wrong as you are already referring to $(this) so it will be like `$('.director-info').find('.director-info h2')` which is not true.

Comment: Thank you, it works. How to end the mouseover function event?

Comment: Do you want to run it only once ?

Comment: Yes, when mouseleave it will be same previous. 
before mousover.

Comment: it will work when just I mouseover it and stop when mouseleave

Comment: You need to add another event `mouseleave` and then apply css again.

Answer (score 1):

Your code was working, please verify that you are calling `mouseover` event when the DOM is ready. I'm using `$(document).ready` fuction for that.

**Edit:** To remove the background color, use `mouseout` event

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".director-info").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
  });
  $(".director-info").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="director-info">Hover me</h2>
```

Comment: How to end the mouseover function event?

Comment: To end `mouseover` use `mouseout` event

Answer (score 1):

I made snippet to help you ;)

```js
$(".director-info").mouseover(function(e){
  $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
  $(this).find("h2").css("color", "#000000");
  $(this).find("h3").css("color", "#605F5F")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="director-info">
  <h2>
    test h2
  </h2>
  <h3>
    test h3
  </h3>
</div>
```